# how to do check the boolean result after assignment in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, inputstreamreader

update: thanks for point out the anwser in elariler question, for complete this question here, the answer is:

```
while ((reader.read(buffer).let {pointer = it; it != -1}) ) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, pointer)
            }
```

Was trying to read something from buffer in a while loop, in Java is done with one line:

```
while ((pointer = reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
```

but in kotling it gets error: Error:(46, 21) Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context

how to to the same thing with kotlin?

```
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))
        var pointer: Int

        while ((pointer = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, pointer)
        }
```

Comment: update pointer in the loop

Comment: thanks Tim!, actually I was asking if there is similar way to assignment and return the result for checking in one line.